# For each + 50 objetos

Tags: javascript

Imagine que GenerarSaludos requiere saludar a más de 50 personas. No sería lógico crear 50 o más líneas de código, sabiendo que los arrays son objetos que tienen el método forEach.

```
function GenerarSaludos() { // ojo con la notaciónde mayuscula inicial para diferenciar de componentes HTML
let personas = [
    { nombre: 'Carlos', apellidos: 'Cuesta Iglesias' },
    { nombre: 'Jordan', apellidos: 'Walke' },
    { nombre: 'Brendan', apellidos: 'Eich' }
];

return (
    <div>
        <Saludo nombre={personas[0].nombre} apellidos={personas[0].apellidos}/>
        <Saludo nombre={personas[1].nombre} apellidos={personas[1].apellidos}/>
        <Saludo nombre={personas[2].nombre} apellidos={personas[2].apellidos}/>
    </div>
);
```

}

RealiZAR los ajustes necesarios para hacer esta mejora en el código.

Comment: No se entiende tu publicación, ¿cuál es la duda?

Comment: Necesito que no sea un codigo de 50 lineas, sino algo en lo que se pueda ingresar los nombres de las personas y saludarlas

Comment: Pues necesitas hacer un `foreach` que recorra cada objeto del `array` para ir creando el **HTML**

Comment: Si, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar lo que has intentado al momento?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Comment: Aun no tengo nada, no se ni como empezar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let Saludos = []
personas.forEach(persona => {
    Saludos.append(
         <Saludo nombre={persona.nombre} apellidos={persona.apellidos} key={persona.nombre+persona.apellidos} />
    )
})
return Saludos;
```

Esto deberías poner en vez de tu return, asumo que es react, deberías especificar eso en tu pregunta

Lo que el código hace sería, crear un arreglo vacío en el que almacenar los saludos que generaras al recorrer las `personas`
Luego con el forEach le dice que por cada item en `personas` él guarde el item en específico en una variable persona y haga lo que está entre llaves.
Entre llaves entonces por cada item le agrega un `<Saludo/>` a tu arreglo para esa persona, pero como seguro querrás renderizar ese arreglo luego no debes olvidarte de agregarle el `key` para que rails pueda diferenciar los items cuando deba volver a renderizar alguna parte de tu arreglo.
Puedes leer más sobre renderizar arreglos en https://es.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
Y en caso de que no sea exigido usar forEach te recomendaría para casos así usar map como en el link de arriba, ya que este ya está optimizado para recorrer y generar un arreglo con un item por cada item que recorra

Comment: A parte del código considero que sería muy útil que le explicaras que hiciste, checa [answer]

Comment: Gracias, editado